# Linux Group Permissions

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions

I have set up an ec2 machine to run an app. To make my deployment script work, I need my deployment user (ec2-user) to have write access to certain directories. I am not versed in linux/unix commands. I am finding my way around using Google.

So the directory in question is /home/ec2-user/uc_social_server/releases. The directory was created by a Capistrano script and for whatever reason it made root the owner of the releases directory even though the script was being run as the ec2-user. An ls -l shows that the root is the owner and that both the owner and group have rwx access:
[image]

My script is failing because it is trying to write to the releases directory as ec2-user but does not have the permission.

I figured if I create a group called deployers and added both root and ec2-user to this group, ec2-user will then have rwx permissions to this directory since ec2-user will belong to same group as root and the group permissions to this directory are rwx. But that did not work.

Should that have worked? If not why (my understanding of the group permission may be totally wrong)?

How can I give ec2-user rwx access to this director?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run:

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user releases ; sudo chgrp -R ec2-user releases
```

or if you want to leave the owner and group as `root` then you can try running this:

```
sudo chmod -R o=rwx releases
```

Read the fine manual for more information on [chmod](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/chmod/), [chgrp](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/chgrp/), and [chown](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/chown/).

Comment: can you please explain what these commands are doing? thanks!

Comment: `chown` changes who the owner is of a given file.  `sudo` lets you run commands as if you were `root`.  `chgrp` changes the group ownership of a given file; `chmod` changes a given file's permissions or `access mode`.  Passing `-R` to these programs makes them act recursively, as in recursively changing the permissions of an entire directory.  These programs expect the following args:  `command-line swithces (e.g. '-R')` `user|group|mode` `file|directory`

Comment: Thanks! I should have read the man pages instead of making you explain it. Sorry~

Comment: @septerr Nah, it's all good, man.  And no problem, glad I could help.  :)

Answer (score 1):

**Unix Rule #1) Don't use root in vain**

I'd recommend that you just sudo to root and change the owner and group of the directory to what you want it to be

- man chown
- man chgrp